# Jmeter in distributed mode is unable to reach slave nodes due to ssl handshake terminated

Tags: ssl, jmeter, taurus

[Getting the following error message when taurus master node tries to reach to jmeter slaves in a the same network on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R7rA.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed instructions from [**Setting up SSL** chapter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl)? If not, it explains everything.

You can also disable secure communication between the master and the slaves by setting [`server.rmi.ssl.disable` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) to `true`

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      server.rmi.ssl.disable: true
```

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) and [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you're supposed to always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.4.1 (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)